# How can I sync two amazon buckets using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS S3 CLI to sync two buckets, following the Amazon CLI S3 SYNC format specified in the documentation, as follows:

```
aws s3 sync s3://source_bucket s3://target_bucket --exclude *.tmp
```

Bug I get the following error:

```
A region must be specified --region or specifying the region in a configuration file or as an environment variable. Alternately, an endpoint can be specified with --endpoint-url
```

I have scoured the internet in addition to AWS CLI docs and find no reference to --region in the context of S3 SYNC.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Probably immaterial, but I am running Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 on a MBPr (16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, quad-core)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable.

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
```

Comment: Much appreciated guys.  Turns out adding it to the command: `--region us-east-1` also worked, and shed light on other missing environment variables as well.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're going between regions: `aws s3 sync s3://source_bucket s3://target_bucket --source-region us-east-1 --region us-west-1`

Comment: @JonathanOliver I tried doing that. specifying both source and dest regions and i'm still getting that error on deletes.  Are you sure that fixes this issue? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=589805&#589805

Comment: @JonathanOliver you really saved my day dude. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry buys but is there any easy to set the enviornmental varible

Comment: @mindmyweb you can use command `aws configure`  to configure it default region . It's only one time setup.